# not able to store .pdf with livewire

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-livewire, func

please am traying to store a pdf link to my database with livewire but it does not work. here is the functionality.

```
$this->validate();
   
$book =[
    'title'=>$this->title,
    'author'=>$this->author,
    'genre'=>$this->genre,
    'link'=>$this->link,
    'store_link'=>$this->store_link,
    'language'=>$this->language,
    'published_date'=>$this->publish_date,
    'ISBN'=>$this->ISBN,
    'description'=>$this->description,
    'tags'=>$this->tags,
    'pages'=>$this->pages,
    'publishing_house'=>$this->publishing_house,
    'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id,

    
];
if ($this->pdf){
    $bookName = $this->pdf->store('/pdfBooks','public');
    $book['pdf'] = $bookName;
}
if ($this->cover) {
    $book['cover'] = $this->cover->store('/booksCover' ,'public');
}

dd($book);
return $bookk = Book::create($book);
```

it works just perfect with images, the pdf file is stored. but unable to write the string to the database. I tried to debug the code with `dd($book);` it does show me the path for the pdf just fine but not in my DB.

`$book` look like this

```
"title" => "booksCover/430rl2fuPEk9fAydBJpCcAho5zkqya80LkfxFP9sv.jpgd"   
"author" => "4"   
"genre" => "554ddd"   
"link" => null   
"store_link" => null   
"language" => "الفرنسية"   
"published_date" => null   
"ISBN" => "555"   
"description" => "this is a spam "   
"tags" => "hello spam"   
"pages" => "50"   
"publishing_house" => "Aseer Alkotob"   
"user_id" => 11   
"pdf" => "pdfBooks/SYZjMLjTzaeNk9OgG0m1jtD106seSOjqkhCtRRCn.pdf"   
"cover" => "booksCover/exg3YvzNrx1Vsb4vV5Qfo2GVZyjwmnlLNC3aagMD.jpg" 
]
```

but the pdf row in database is empty.

Comment: It would be useful if you showed us the output from the `dd($book)`

Comment: Also what does `$this->pdf->store()` do ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes there should be a slash so it would know that the file should be stored in public storage. for the dd here is what it shows

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
`"title" => "booksCover/430rl2fuPEk9fAydBJpCcAho5zkqya80LkfxFP9sv.jpgd"
  "author" => "4"
  "genre" => "554ddd"
  "link" => null
  "store_link" => null
  "language" => "الفرنسية"
  "published_date" => null
  "ISBN" => "555"
  "description" => "this is a spam "
  "tags" => "hello spam"
  "pages" => "50"
  "publishing_house" => "Aseer Alkotob"
  "user_id" => 11
  "pdf" => "pdfBooks/SYZjMLjTzaeNk9OgG0m1jtD106seSOjqkhCtRRCn.pdf"
  "cover" => "booksCover/exg3YvzNrx1Vsb4vV5Qfo2GVZyjwmnlLNC3aagMD.jpg"
]` which is what i wanted to achieve in my DB

Comment: Information like that is UNREADABLE in a comment, put it into the question with an EDIT

Comment: _unable to write the string to the database_ So is that column blank, or what?

Comment: Check if your book model has the fields pdf and cover in fillable array...

Comment: @Anand thank you so much dude. the pdf field was actually missing from the fillable. I don't know how I did missed That